# Deploying .Net web project to shared hosting with DevExpress

Tags: c#, asp.net, deployment, devexpress

I am going to start building an ASP.NET project and I need to use DevExpress DLLs. I am wondering if those DLLs work on shared hosting. What should I do to make sure that DevExpress DLLs will work for sure? How should I choose the hosting company? What things should I consider before choosing the hosting company?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Providing you are publishing to your own instance of a website then you will have no problem with the DevExpress dll's. Just copy all the DevExpress required assemblies into the 'bin' folder on your host site. There is an 'Assembly Deployment Tool' that makes this easy. https://help.devexpress.com/#AssemblyDeploymentTool/CustomDocument17237